# unable to print or scan on Ubuntu 20.04 Brother DCP-195C and Canon LBP6020

Tags: printing

After installing 20.04 on my desktop, my printer has stopped working.

Printer: Brother DCP-195C and Canon LBP6020, connected via USB. installed. cups installed.
printers seem to show on cups but still can't print, tried to launch scan on brother printer it starts scanning but nothing is scanned or shown on my Desktop

I even downloaded the drivers from the printers' official sites

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had maybe same problem with official drivers.
My DCP195C says waiting for Tasklist, but did no print.

Just deinstalled the printers in the printer menu.
*Activities -> Printer-Options -> Extended Options*
They were created by the drivers on the official brother website.

I installed cups with sudo, but it seems to be installed already. I plug in my printer and choose to install it over usb-port. Now it printed the testpage correctly.
Scanning not tested, maybe try by xsane.